# I want to show this view using 'html' ...but it is giving "TypeError at /area/"

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django coding....i want to show whatever is there in area_distnce.html...below is my code

Thanks in advance....

### Distance.py

```
from  django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template.context import RequestContext


def area_distance(request):    
    return render_to_response('area_distance.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from areas.Distance import area_distance


urlpatterns = patterns('',       
url(r'^area/$','area_distance',name = 'area_distance'),)
```

When i run his it is giving
    TypeError at /area/
    'str' object is not callable

Comment: it is worked..:)at first i did not put 'html' file in templates folder...so later i have creted templates folder then i have kept my 'html' file by giving path in settings.py...:)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have written view function `area_distance()` in `Distance.py` instead of `views.py`.

So you may want to update your `urls.py` to appropriately use that

```
url(r'^area/$', area_distance,name = 'area_distance'),)
---------------^ note no '...'
```

As you are doing `from areas.Distance import area_distance` this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
from  django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.context import RequestContext

def area_distance(request):   
    a= 1
    b = a+1

    t = get_template('area_distance.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, locals())
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))

#url.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from areas.Distance import area_distance
urlpatterns = patterns('',       
url(r'^area/$',area_distance,name = 'area_distance'),)

#template
{{ a }}
{{ b }}
```